linking std::filesystem on gcc 8.5 in EL8 container
I have an EL8 container on MacOS 14.5, running g++ 8.5
I have looked on here for similar issues and none seem to apply here or provide the solution I am looking for
The following code (test.cpp) gives me no issues with clang++ ($ clang++ -std=c++17 test.cpp) , natively or on my container
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    for (const auto& fit : filesystem::directory_iterator(string("tempdir")))
    {
        cout << fit << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

However, using g++ 8.5 ($ g++ -std=c++17 -lstdc++fs test.cpp), I get the following linking error
[root@b67764d976a2 sandbox]# g++ -std=c++17 -lstdc++fs test.cpp 
 /tmp/ccwP6RaW.o: In function `main':
 test.cpp:(.text+0x148): undefined reference to   `std::filesystem::__cxx11::directory_iterator::operator*() const'
 test.cpp:(.text+0x181): undefined reference to `std::filesystem::__cxx11::directory_iterator::operator++()'
 /tmp/ccwP6RaW.o: In function `std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::path(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&, std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::format)':
 test.cpp:(.text._ZNSt10filesystem7__cxx114pathC2EONSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS1_6formatE[_ZNSt10filesystem7__cxx114pathC5EONSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS1_6formatE]+0x4f): undefined reference to `std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_M_split_cmpts()'
 /tmp/ccwP6RaW.o: In function `std::filesystem::__cxx11::directory_iterator::directory_iterator(std::filesystem::__cxx11::path const&)':
 test.cpp:(.text._ZNSt10filesystem7__cxx1118directory_iteratorC2ERKNS0_4pathE[_ZNSt10filesystem7__cxx1118directory_iteratorC5ERKNS0_4pathE]+0x26): undefined reference to `std::filesystem::__cxx11::directory_iterator::directory_iterator(std::filesystem::__cxx11::path const&, std::filesystem::directory_options, std::error_code*)'
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

As far as I know, -std=c++17 and -lstdc++fs are the appropriate linking flags, correct?

This is a common gotcha, put the -lstdc++fs after the test.cpp

that is about the silliest thing ever but worked.

Starting from gcc9, -lstdc++fs is not required anymore.
